# Socket client blocks forever

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, java-io

I'm coding socket client in Java.
In the program, I want to get information from server.
When the server receives "GET_LIGHTS" command, it sends back data in JSON format.

But in my code, `bw.write()` and `bw.flush()` doesn't work before `socket.close()`.
So, the BufferedReader object is not ready: `br.ready()` returns false.

Is there any mistake in my code?

The client code is shown bellow.

```
package monitor;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SocketClient {
    static private int port;
    static private String hostName;
    private Socket socket;

    public SocketClient(String host, int port) {
        this.hostName = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    // get lights by JSON
    public void getLights() {
        try {
            // generate socket
            InetSocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress(hostName, port);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(endpoint);

            // setting
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(out);

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

            // send command
            bw.write("GET_LIGHTS");
            bw.flush();

            // receive message from server
            System.out.println(br.readLine());

            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initLights(ArrayList<Light> lights) {
        getLights();
    }

}
```

Edited:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SocketServer extends Thread{
    static final int PORT = 44344;
    static private ILS ils;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    public SocketServer(ILS ils) {
        this.ils = ils;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        serverSocket = null;
        System.out.println("Server: listening");

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(true){
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
                String in;
                while( (in = br.readLine()) != null ){
                    cmd.add(in);
                }
                command(cmd);
                if( socket != null){
                    socket.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if( serverSocket != null){
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                serverSocket = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // send message to client
    private void sendMessage(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        try {
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
            bw.write(str + "¥n");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // error
    private void printError(String err) {
        String str = "ERROR; ";
        str += err;
        sendMessage(str);
    }

    public void command(ArrayList<String> cmd) {
        String mode = cmd.get(0);
        if(mode == null){

        }else switch(mode){
            case "MANUAL_SIG-ALL":
                System.out.println("全照明一括 信号値指定調光");
                manualSigAll(cmd.get(1));
                break;
            case "MANUAL_SIG-INDIVIDUAL":
                System.out.println("全照明独立 信号値指定調光");
                manualSigIndividual(cmd.get(1));
                break;
            case "MANUAL_ID-SIG":
                System.out.println("照明ID・信号値指定調光");
                manualIDSig(cmd.get(1));
                break;
            case "MANUAL_ID-RELATIVE":
                System.out.println("照明ID・相対信号値指定調光");
                break;
            case "DOWNLIGHT_ALL":
                System.out.println("Downlight: All Control");
                downlightAll(cmd.get(1));
                break;
            case "DOWNLIGHT_INDIVIDUAL":
                System.out.println("Downlight: Individual control");
                downlightIndividual(cmd.get(1));
                break;
            case "GET_LIGHTS":
                System.out.println("Sending lights via JSON");
                sendLights();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error: 不明なmode command");
        }
    }

    // 全照明一括 信号値指定調光
    private void manualSigAll(String sigs) {
        if(sigs == null) {
            System.out.println("信号値のフォーマットを確認してください");
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] buf = sigs.split(",");
            for(String i:buf) s.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
            for(Light l: ils.getLights()) {
                l.setLumPct((double)s.get(0)/255.0*100.0);
                l.setSignal(s.get(0), s.get(1));
            }
        }
        // 調光
        ils.downlightDimmer.send();

    }

    // 全照明独立 信号値指定調光
    private void manualSigIndividual(String sigs) {
        if(sigs == null) {
            System.out.println("信号値のフォーマットを確認してください");
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] buf = sigs.split(",");
            for(String i:buf) s.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
            for(int i=0; i<ils.getLights().size(); i++) {
                ils.getLights().get(i).setSignal(s.get(0), s.get(1));
                s.remove(0);
                s.remove(0);
            }
        }
        ils.downlightDimmer.send();
    }

    // 照明ID・信号値指定調光
    private void manualIDSig(String sigs) {
        if(sigs == null) {
            System.out.println("信号値のフォーマットを確認してください");
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] buf = sigs.split(",");
            for(String i:buf) s.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
            System.out.println(s.get(0));
            ils.getLight(s.get(0)).setSignal(s.get(1), s.get(2));
        }
        ils.downlightDimmer.send();
    }

    private void downlightAll(String cmd) {
        if(cmd == null) {
            printError("Check for data command.");
        } else {
            ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] buf = cmd.split(",");
            for(String i:buf) data.add(Double.parseDouble(i));
            for(Light l: ils.getLights()) {
                l.setLumPct(data.get(0));
                l.setTemperature(data.get(1));
            }
        }
        // dimming
        ils.downlightDimmer.send();
    }

    private void downlightIndividual(String cmd) {
        if(cmd == null) {
            printError("Check for data command.");
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Double> lumPct = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

            String[] buf = cmd.split(",");
            if(buf.length % 3 != 0) {printError("invalid number of data.");}

            for(int i=0; i<buf.length/3; i++) {
                int n = i*3;
                try {
                    id.add(Integer.parseInt(buf[n]));
                    lumPct.add(Double.parseDouble(buf[n + 1]));
                    temp.add(Integer.parseInt(buf[n + 2]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    printError(e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }

            while (id.size() > 0) {
                // update light object
                Light light = ils.getLight(id.get(0));
                light.setLumPct(lumPct.get(0));
                light.setTemperature(temp.get(0));

                // remove data from array list
                id.remove(0);
                lumPct.remove(0);
                temp.remove(0);
            }

            // dimming
            ils.downlightDimmer.send();

        }
    }

    private void sendLights() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "";
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(ils.getLights());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // output
        sendMessage(json);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server is using `readLine()`, as is probable, it will block until you close the connection, because you aren't *sending* a line.

Add `bw.newLine()` before the `flush()`.

**EDIT** As predicted, your server isn't sending lines, so it needs the same treatment as above. However there is an anterior problem:

```
while( (in = br.readLine()) != null ){
    cmd.add(in);
}
```

This loop in the server cannot possibly exit *until* the client closes the connection. You should process a line at a time in the server, or else moderate your expectations of the client's behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My server is using `readLine()`.
As you suggested, I tried to insert `bw.newLine()`, but the situation was same.

Comment: @Ryoto Maybe your server code is wrong. You probably shouldn't be using `br.ready()` for anything there.

Comment: @Ryoto So show us your server code. Is the *server* sending a line, for example? Or misusing `ready()`?

Comment: @EJP I edited my question to add server code. It contains some Japanese characters sorry.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your kindness. It turned out that the server receive commands from client but as you predicted, the loop can't exit until the client closes the connection.
So, I have to moderate the sever's behavior.